# Is there way to view data on RDS?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have few questions to ask about Amazon RDS

1. I was able to create an instance and I was able to view data that I insert using the below code and I was able to see the results through workbench, but is there any way to view data on RDS?
2. I have a huge data set, probably containing 80k tuples, I read this data from csv and I put it in the database, does changing to a better instance will affect the speed of inserting the data to the database, because I tried a larger instance with around 7.5 GB RAM, but it didn't work, insertion was very slow.What could be the problem? am I not connected properly?

I used the following code to connect

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='west........{the endpoint}', port=3306, db='clouddb', user='{my_username}',passwd='{my_password')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE consumer_complaint(Complaint VARCHAR(255),Product VARCHAR(255),Subproduct VARCHAR(255),Issue VARCHAR(255),State VARCHAR(255),ZIPcode VARCHAR(255),Company VARCHAR(255),Companyresponse VARCHAR(255),Timelyresponse VARCHAR(255),Consumerdisputed VARCHAR(255));')
```

I'm getting no errors in connecting.

Comment: "View" the data in what sense? You have already demonstrated that you can perform a query and view the result set! Do you mean can you connect a MySQL GUI/WebUI to an RDS instance? If so; short answer is yes.

Comment: Oh yes , i just had doubts if i'm getting connected properly , so wanted see the database/data on the RDS. For example when you create a database in google cloud(CloudSQL) you can export the data from database via query on the cloud, i wanted to know if there's something similar to it for RDS.  
Also any idea about the insertion speed?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question. RDS just exposes a MysQL or Postgres service with whatever SQL API(s) they typically/normally expose. So anything that can speak MySQL/Postgres can do anything it wants to the RDS instance. The *only* restriction AFAIK being that you can't "shell" into the EC2 that powers the instance.